# Как выровнять сцену с отступами от левого края и верха graphicsView?

Tags: qt

Каким методом можно выровнять сцену с отступами от левого края и верха graphicsView?
Что-то типа 'ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);' но с отступами.

Comment: Зачем это нужно можете прояснить? Сцену нельзя разместить с отступом

Comment: Да сделал уже :). Надо было писать -4 -4 graphicsScene->setSceneRect(-4,-4,544,1104); Вы правы были